# Granular 'Up to the minute' data recoverability of mySQL database data

Tags: mysql, database, recovery

I operate a web-based online game with a mySQL backend. Every day many writes are performed against hundreds of related tables holding user data.

Frequently a user's account will become compromised. I would like the ability to restore the user's data to a certain point in time prior to the attack without affecting any other user data.

I'm aware of binary logging in mySQL, but as far as I know this is whole-database recovery up to a certain point in time. I would like a more granular solution, ie able to specify which tables, which rows etc. 
What should I be looking into? What are the general best-practices?

Comment: Couldn't you implement some kind of data revisions yourself? Like in Wikipedia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create and use audit tables (populated through triggers) you can always get back to the data for one particular user in any table.

Be sure to write your general restore script before you need it though. Much easier to put in a userid into a script that you already have available than to sit there looking at the audit tables going, how do I do this again.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL (or any other RDBMS that I'm aware of) is not able to do that by itself. Therefore you should implement that yourself in your application layer.

Answer (score 0):

This is (without external modules) not possible.

As thejh in the comments suggested, revisions would be a good solution. When you only need to work with userdata, create a table that resembles the usertable with additional timestamp or similar and run a cron job once a week/day/.. that copies the userdata that has recently been modified (additional flags/dates in the actual user table) into this table.